# Busy? Working? Symbol

Tags: usability, gui-design, symbols

Are there any unicode symbols that can represent an app being busy?

I'd like to represent on a text-based interface that the app is working on something in the background. What symbols may accurately convey this?

Of course it doesn't have to be unicode, I could make a font to go with the app that contains the best possible symbol for this wide use-case scenario.

Comment: Can the user continue with their work while this process is taking place? What kind of app is this? I ask because there are some icons, but there's also some placement issues in the UI depending on if users need to be informed vs. halted in their workflow.

Comment: @MikeM yeah the user can continue. I'd like to make it a feature of a zsh theme for terminal.

Comment: You already asked the same question yesterday and it was closed because symbol and icon suggestions are *off-topic* here. Please don't do this. Instead, read the final part of https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic which has help for your problem

Comment: @Devin they aren't off-topic here. In fact, the very meta question which the close reason links to is full of answers in favour of these types of question.

Comment: I didn't say I'm against it, I said it's off topic. And rules are the same for everybody. Just explainng why it's being closed since yesterday you demanded an explanation. I didn't vote to close that question, but did vote to close this one. Not only for being off topic, but because it's repeated.

Comment: @Devin "I didn't say I'm against it" neither did I, but you still vote to close it. And you haven't offered an explanation, nor has anyone else.

Comment: I clearly explained it: is off topic and repeated, both are reasons to close a question. I'm taking my time to explaIn it, not sure what else do you need. What I think about this question's reason for being off topic is completely irrelevant, rules are meant for everybody, despite what I may think about this highly controversial topic

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [dotted circle symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25cc/index.htm), but it's still not great.

If you can animate the text, try doing a loading bar, like this:

██████▁▁▁▁▁▁